# Using a 30V Switch on a 28V load

Tags: switches, switch-mode-power-supply

For a project I'm working on, I wanted to use a LED Switch for a [28V load](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/65/LRA-Series_Details__26_COS_0-268479.pdf), and the switch itself is rated for 30V, 10A. Even though the switch is within spec, is it good practice to use a switch rated for the voltage you need, and not oversize it (i.e. using a 60V switch for a 28V load)? This is the [power supply](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/167/CLP0228_DS_V1_1-1390100.pdf) I am using in case that information is needed. And the load isn't anything specific, it could be anything within the power limit of the supply.

Comment: There should be 2 specifications, voltage and current (amperage), what is the other value?

Comment: It's rated for 30V, 10A. Just made an edit.

Comment: It might be ok, but I work in a world where you derate things. If this is a home project you probably are ok (note the ±3% tolerance on the 28V output). I will note that the link you provided for the switch is for an incandescent light, not LED, and the options for lamp voltage only go to 24V.

Comment: Load can't be anything. It should be within the power supply's watt rating.

Comment: When I mean't anything, I meant any device within the power limit.

Comment: the power supply can provide maximum 198.8  watts.

Comment: The switch can handle 300 watts, So you can drive anything.

Comment: Switch as in MOSFET or mechanical? If MOSFET, the inductance of the cable and 10 A being broken will be enough to push it way over the 30 V limit.

Answer (score 2):

Are these AC or DC?  It's probably not so very important at only 28 volts DC, but you should be in the habit of being very cautious about DC ratings.

DC does not have zero crossings like AC does, and so once a DC arc is struck, nothing will stop it.  This makes things extra difficult for DC switches, particularly of higher voltages than this.  I've seen a 600VDC contactor goobed together out of a 3-pole AC contactor that is rated 960VAC (intended for 3-phase power).  **All three poles were wired in series**.  Even then, the device was only rated for 140 volts DC, so its spec was being exceeded even if we only ask each pole to interrupt 200VDC!

Most switches will have a DC voltage and/or current rating quite below their AC rating.   You have to check it!